# Find percent increase and diff regardless of the date order (in Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I wish to calculate the percent increase of the sum of a particular group over a time period. Here is the dataset:

```
   date      size               type
   1/1/2020  3                   a
   1/1/2020  13                  b
   1/1/2020  1                   c
   2/1/2020  51                  a
   2/1/2019  10                  b
```

Desired output

Then find percent diff and diff from earliest date,

```
date       diff     percentdiff    type

2/1/2020   48       1600           a
1/1/2020   3        30             b
1/1/2020   0        0              c
```

We see that group 'a' went from ***3 to 51***, (***from 1/1/2020 to 2/1/2020***) which gives us a difference of ***48***, and a ***percent difference of 1600%***
***Group c is 0 because there is no change.***

```
Percent Increase/Change is  final-inital/initial * 100
```

This is what I have tried:

```
  df1 = df.groupby(['type','date'])['size'].agg(lambda x: 
  (x.iloc[-1]/x.iloc[0]-1)*100).to_frame('increase')
  df1['diff'] = df.groupby(['type','date']).agg(lambda x:x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])
```

I am still researching this. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: why the date for in the desired output is `1/1/2020` for `b` and `2/1/2020` for `a` ?

Comment: First use `groupy`  then `GrouBy.agg` with `diff` and `pct_change`

Comment: It is taking the latest date stamp   a earliest date is 1/1/2020 and then ends at 2/1/2020   'b' starts at 2/1/2019 and ends at 1/1/2020

Comment: ok @Ch3steR group by date, and then groupby.agg type and then perform the diff and pct change? I believe. Let me research this. Thank you!

Comment: how `177.777%` and `26.0869%` are computed ?

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ let me update I believe it is 1600% for 'a' and 30% for 'b' 3 to 51 for 'a' and then 10 to 13 for 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more concise solution, but this works:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
grouped = df.sort_values('date').groupby(['type'])

output = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': grouped['date'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).values,
  'diff': grouped['size'].agg(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(0).iloc[-1]).values,
  'percentdiff': grouped['size'].agg(lambda x: x.pct_change().fillna(0).iloc[-1] * 100).values,
  'type': grouped['type'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0]).values
})
```

[demo](https://repl.it/@riless/64673863)

Comment: ok @Ghilas Thank you for posting this. I will try this and build off of this

Comment: How did you make it so that the code takes the earliest date? I am trying to learn what you did? thanks @ghilas

Comment: @Lynnette this is the result of `.sort_values('date')` then `grouped['date'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])`